# how to add animation when table view row height is changing?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I am trying to make a FAQ view controller, I know that there is pods called 'FAQView' to make this FAQ page, but I need to customize, so make it by myself. I want that my end result will be like this

[image]

there is a little bit animation when the row is expanded, I need to add that animation. and My table view for this FAQ is like this

[image]

I want to add animation when the row height changes from let say 80 to 140 in a certain cell

here is my code, my view controller code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var FAQs = [FAQ]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var selectedRow : Int?
    var cellIsExpanded : Bool = false {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        getFAQ()        
    }

    func getFAQ() {

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return FAQs.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FAQCell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.FAQData = FAQs[indexPath.row]
        cell.expandButton.tag = indexPath.row

        // to implement FAQCellDelegate
        cell.cellDelegate = self

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        var height:CGFloat = CGFloat()

        if cellIsExpanded == false {
            height = 80
        } else {
            if indexPath.row == selectedRow {
                height = 160
            } else {
                height = 80
            }
        }
        return height
    }
}

extension ViewController : FAQCellDelegate {
    func didPressButton(isExpanded: Bool, tag: Int) {
        cellIsExpanded = isExpanded
        selectedRow = tag

    }
}
```

and my Table View Cell code is like below

```
import UIKit

protocol FAQCellDelegate : class {
    func didPressButton(isExpanded: Bool, tag: Int)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var expandButton: UIButton!

    var expanded = false
    var FAQData : FAQ! {
        didSet {
            questionLabel.text = FAQData.question
            answerLabel.text = FAQData.answer
        }
    }

    weak var cellDelegate: FAQCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func expandButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if expanded == true {
            expanded = false
            cellDelegate?.didPressButton(isExpanded: expanded, tag: expandButton.tag)

        } else {
            expanded = true
            cellDelegate?.didPressButton(isExpanded: expanded, tag: expandButton.tag)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to reload row !!  in `didPressButton`

Comment: i do it in property observer var cellIsExpanded

Comment: Your issue is your cell is getting collapsed as soon as it expanded just like in your animation ?

Comment: no, I have no issue to populate table view. i just need to add the animation when the row height is changing from 80 to 160 and vice versa. I am sorry, I have changed my .gif above. usually in the tutorial I see people using animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: ..... but i don't understand animation

Comment: Instead of changing the height of row, add/delete row on click using this method "tableView.insertRows(at: [], with: .fade)". you will get the same animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do like this way, I have made it for simple tableview. Please do appropriate changes.

Declare `selectedIndexs` like this,

```
var selectedIndexs: [IndexPath: Bool] = [:]
```

Implement this method,

```
func cellIsSelected(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if let number = selectedIndexs[indexPath] {
        return number
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Now on `didSelectRowAt indexPath`

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        let isSelected = !self.cellIsSelected(indexPath: indexPath)
        selectedIndexs[indexPath] = isSelected

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Implement `heightForRowAt indexPath` method like this,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.cellIsSelected(indexPath: indexPath) {
        return 100
    } else {
        return 44
    }
}
```

I have animated TableViewCell's height when user tap on any cell in `didSelectRowAt indexPath` method, you can do it in button tap event also. Make necessary changes and its done.

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: could you please help me a  little bit more to fix your code to set table view cell height in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271646/how-to-set-cell-row-height-in-table-view-if-it-exceed-its-indexpath-row ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Don't reload the tableview instead call the below method when 'cellIsExpanded' is set. Use following codes

In iOS 11,

```
- (void)performBatchUpdates:(void (NS_NOESCAPE ^ _Nullable)(void))updates completion:(void (^ _Nullable)(BOOL finished))completion
```

iOS 10 or below,

```
- (void)beginUpdates;
- (void)endUpdates;
```

Comment: it is onwards ios11. should be added in answer

Answer (score 0):

Add "self.tableView.reloadData()" line in didPressButton function like below

```
func didPressButton(isExpanded: Bool, tag: Int) {
        cellIsExpanded = isExpanded
        selectedRow = tag
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

To Add animation on expandButtonDidPressed function like below

```
@IBAction func expandButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if expanded == true {
            expanded = false
            cellDelegate?.didPressButton(isExpanded: expanded, tag: expandButton.tag)

        } else {
            expanded = true
            cellDelegate?.didPressButton(isExpanded: expanded, tag: expandButton.tag)

        }

self.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
    sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
})
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. my bad, sorry sir, I mean, animation when table view is expanded, drop down animation, not the button, when the row height of table view change from 80 to 160. could You please help me this one ?  :)

Comment: Yes , Sorry I got it wrong. I have updated the answer please check. You forgot to reload the tableview.

Comment: Thanks sir, but maybe I have my english is bad, I have no issue to populate table view. i just need to add the animation when the row height is changing from 80 to 160 and vice versa. I am sorry, I have changed my .gif above. usually in the tutorial I see people using animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: ..... but i don't understand animation

Answer (score 0):

Go for [**CollapsibleHeader**](https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section). I have been using this in couple of my apps. Provides an elegant animation, exactly what you want. Not to mention, is quite easy to integrate.