# how to set cell row height in table view if it exceed its indexpath.row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make a FAQ view controller using table view, I need little bit fix in the UI. here is the display of my FAQ VC right now

(please ignore the red line)

[image]

[image]

as we can see, basically there are 2 row height, 80 & 160. if the row is tapped (selected) the row height will expand from 80 (yellow line) to 160 (purple line).

I want to make the row height under the last question is still 80 not 160. I have tried but I can't set the row below the last question. here is my code I use

```
class FAQVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var retryButton: DesignableButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var FAQs = [FAQ]()
    var selectedIndexs: [IndexPath: Bool] = [:]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getFAQData()


    }

}

extension FAQVC : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // MARK: - Table View Delegate and Datasource


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return FAQs.count
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FAQCell") as! FAQCell
        cell.FAQData = FAQs[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if self.cellIsSelected(indexPath: indexPath) {
          return 160
        } else {
            return 80
        }


    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        let isSelected = !self.cellIsSelected(indexPath: indexPath)
        selectedIndexs[indexPath] = isSelected



        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }


    func cellIsSelected(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        if let number = selectedIndexs[indexPath] {
            return number
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why you want to set the row height under the last question? I think you should remove all tableview separators under the last question

Comment: @Alexa289, You can use UITableAutomaticDimension for cell height, which adjust cell height based on the content.

Comment: @PPL yes It is unnecessary actually, but I have a complaint from UI UX team, how to remove table view separator under the last question?

Comment: @Alexa289 Please find my answer to remove extra separators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put this code in your **viewDidLoad()** method of your controller.

```
YOUR_TABLE_VIEW.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

this will remove extra separators.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way to do this would be to add an extra empty cell at the end with row height 80

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return FAQs.count + 1
}
```

Also, make sure you make a change to cellForRowAt method to accommodate this :

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     if indexPath.row < FAQs.count {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FAQCell") as! FAQCell
        cell.FAQData = FAQs[indexPath.row]

        return cell
     }
     return UITableViewCell()
}
```

EDIT :

I just read that you don't really require separators after the last cell. In that case look here https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/01/02/remove-extra-separator-lines-uitableview/